# Cálculo máximo vector

Tags: java, c++, recursión

Tengo una duda con un ejercicio que no me sale:

> Impleméntese  la  función recursiva`template <> vector_t<int>::max(int> i, int d)const` que   lleva   a   cabo la búsqueda    recursiva   del elemento máximo dentro  del vector  invocante,  en  los extremos    i y d del   vector.

Intenté buscar ejemplos para entender mejor el problema, que me generaron dudas, en este ejemplo:

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = {90,5,125,72,1,-50,8};
        System.out.println("Mayor: " + Mayor(array, 0, array[0]));
    }

    static int Mayor(int[] array, int n, int mayor)
    {
        if (n == array.length)
            return mayor;

        if (array[n] > mayor)
            mayor = array[n];

        return Mayor(array, ++n, mayor);
    }
}
```

Mi duda: por qué al hacer la llamada recursiva `return Mayor(array, ++n, mayor);`¿ qué está haciendo con `++n`?

¿Por qué se hace esa llamada recursiva?

Este es el código que intenté hacer yo para hacer el ejercicio pero me lío a la hora de hacer la llamada recursiva

```
template<>
vector_t<int>::max(int i, int d) const {

double maximo = v_[0];

double EPS = 1 . 10^-5;

while(i<=d){

 if(|v_[i] - máximo| > EPS)
   maximo= v_[0]

}//no se  como hacer la llamada recursiva
```

Gracias

Comment: En el ejemplo hace n++ pq se fija en la posicion siguiente para comparar con el maximo.. en tu caso... de recursivo no tiene nada..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a contestar a tus preguntas:

> mi duda: por qué al hacer la llamada recursiva return Mayor(array,
>   ++n, mayor);¿ qué está haciendo con ++n?

Lo que está haciendo con el `++n` es incrementar el valor de `n` en `1` antes de  llamarse a si mismo, es decir, volver a llamar a la función `Mayor` (esto es la recursividad).

> ¿por qué se hace esa llamada recursiva?

Decir lo primero que lo que intenta resolver el ejercicio (calcular el Mayor de un array de `int`) se puede implementar con una función linear, pero si lo estas estudiando por motivos pedagógicos, te lo explico.

La primera vez que llamas a la función Mayor, lo haces con el array completo, comenzando por el elemento 0 (el primero) y eligiendo como "mayor" el primer número que se encuentre en el array.

```
Mayor(array, 0, array[0])
```

Siempre que llamas a Mayor, lo que hace es:

1. Si el parámetro `n` es igual al número de elementos en el array, ya has recorrido todos los elementos, devuelves el valor Mayor que hayas encontrado.

   ```
   if (n == array.length)
       return mayor;
   ```
2. Ahora, si el elemento `n` es mayor al `mayor` que te pasaron por parámetro, te quedas con este nuevo `mayor`

   ```
   if (array[n] > mayor)
       mayor = array[n];
   ```
3. Y aquí viene la gracia de la recursividad, al retornar lo que haces es volver a llamarte, es decir, volver a llamar a la función que se está ejecutando pero alterando los valores que recibe como parámetro.

En tu ejemplo, pasaría algo así:

```
 Llamada                      | n | mayor | array[n] | invocación desde
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 return Mayor(array, 0, 90);  | 0 | 90    | 90       | main()
 return Mayor(array, 1, 90);  | 1 | 90    | 5        | Mayor retorno 1
 return Mayor(array, 2, 90);  | 2 | 90    | 125      | Mayor retorno 2
 return Mayor(array, 3, 125); | 3 | 125   | 72       | Mayor retorno 3
 return Mayor(array, 4, 125); | 4 | 125   | 1        | Mayor retorno 4
 return Mayor(array, 5, 125); | 5 | 125   | -50      | Mayor retorno 5
 return Mayor(array, 6, 125); | 6 | 125   | 8        | Mayor retorno 6
 return Mayor(array, 7, 125); | 7 | 125   | EXIT     | Mayor retorno 7
```

Como ves, el parámetro `n` funciona como índice para saber *por donde vas* y en el parámetro `mayor` almacenas cual es el mayor número que has encontrado hasta el momento.

Con respecto a tu función, no es recursiva, tan sólo tienes un bucle... por lo que espero que te sirva de ayuda para entender como funciona la recursividad.